# Proper way to transform nested lists to nested maps

Tags: java, performance, array, hash-map

I want to transform a list of lists of lists that I have in a MongoDB document into a map of maps of maps in my java Domain class.

The problem I have is that the fields are mixed between the levels. For instance, the value of the deepest list in the document is the key of the first level map in the domain class.

Here is a representation of my classes.

Mongo Document and subLevels:

```
public class Level1 {

Integer categoryId;

List<Level2> level2List;
```

SubLevel2:

```
public class Level2 {

Integer nPlayers;

List<Level3> Level3List;
```

SubLevel3:

```
public class Level3 {

Integer duration;

Integer price;
```

And here the Domain classes:

```
static class MyClass {
    Map<Integer, Map<Integer, MySubClass>> prices;
}

static class MySubClass {
    Map<Integer, Integer> ppd;
}
```

And here is the mapping function I coded:

```
private static MyClass map(List<Level1> field) {
    MyClass res = new MyClass();
    MySubClass mySubClass = new MySubClass();
    Map<Integer, Integer> sc = new HashMap<>();
    mySubClass.ppd= sc;

    res.prices = new HashMap<>();

    field.forEach(x -> {
        x.level2List.forEach(y -> {
            y.Level3List.forEach(z -> {
                res.prices.putIfAbsent(y.nPlayers, new HashMap<>());
                res.prices.get(y.nPlayers).putIfAbsent(x.categoryId, mySubClass);
                res.prices.get(y.nPlayers).get(x.categoryId).ppd.put(z.duration, z.price);
            });
        });
    });
    return res;
}
```

I had to use 3 nested `for` in the end. I was trying to improve this by using Java `Stream` but I didn't succeed.

Can somebody give me a hand to find a better solution?

Comment: *Stream processing* is a useful hammer. Not every processing task is a nail.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review@SE. Useful reviews need context: May there be more attributes to `Level2` (a name to improve) in the future? Is `nPlayers` always the length of `List<> Level3List`? As initially presented, the "level classes" are incomplete. For tinkering/exploring alternatives, a test scaffold or even a `main()` triggering basic functions was great. See [How to get the best value out of Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436).

Comment: the size of nPlayers is 4 and the size of levl3List is 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is probably not a good idea but you haven't given us enough context to provide any more detail ("what are you actually doing?"). It's not a good idea for a long list of reasons, including -

- the data structure is very complicated
- the operation you're performing relies a lot on mutation
- the operation you're performing, if expressed in immutable, functional code requires a lot of explicit resolution on duplicate keys

I highly doubt it's appropriate for you to reuse a single `mySubclass` instance the way you are.

A vaguely equivalent streamed implementation will look like

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Program {
    public record Level1(
        Integer categoryId,
        List<Level2> level2List
    ){}

    public record Level2(
        Integer nPlayers,
        List<Level3> level3List
    ){}

    public record Level3(
        Integer duration,
        Integer price
    ){}

    public record MyClass(
        Map<Integer, Map<Integer, MySubClass>> prices
    ){}

    public record MySubClass(
        Map<Integer, Integer> ppd
    ){}

    private record FlatKeys(
        Level1 level1,
        Level2 level2
    ){}

    private static MySubClass mergeCategory(MySubClass left, MySubClass right)
    {
        // What happens if, within equal nplayers keys, there are also equal category keys?
        return new MySubClass(
            Stream.concat(
                left.ppd.entrySet().stream(),
                right.ppd.entrySet().stream()
            )
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                // We assume these are unique.
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                Map.Entry::getValue
            ))
        );
    }

    private static Map<Integer, MySubClass> mergeNPlayers(
        Map<Integer, MySubClass> left,
        Map<Integer, MySubClass> right
    )
    {
        // What happens if there are equal nplayer keys?
        return Stream.concat(
            left.entrySet().stream(),
            right.entrySet().stream()
        ).collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Map.Entry::getKey,
            Map.Entry::getValue,
            Program::mergeCategory
        ));
    }

    private static MyClass map(List<Level1> field) {
        var prices =
            field.stream().flatMap(
                level1 -> level1.level2List.stream()
                    .map(level2 -> new FlatKeys(level1, level2))
            )
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                flat -> flat.level2.nPlayers,
                flat -> Map.of(
                    flat.level1.categoryId,
                    new MySubClass(
                        flat.level2.level3List.stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            Level3::duration, Level3::price
                        ))
                    )
                ),
                Program::mergeNPlayers
            ));

        return new MyClass(prices);
    }

    private static List<Level1> makeTestData() {
        return List.of(
            new Level1(
                1,
                List.of(
                    new Level2(
                        97,
                        List.of(
                            new Level3(4000, 20),
                            new Level3(3000, 30)
                        )
                    ),
                    new Level2(
                        98,
                        List.of(
                            new Level3(4001, 21),
                            new Level3(3001, 31)
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
            new Level1(
                1,
                List.of(
                    new Level2(
                        97,
                        List.of(
                            new Level3(4002, 22),
                            new Level3(3002, 32)
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Level1> outerLevel = makeTestData();
        MyClass result = map(outerLevel);
    }
}
```

but my guess is that, in the rest of the program you haven't shown us, there are design issues that - if fixed - would prevent all of this from being necessary.

Comment: NPlayers key is unique with a size of 4. So in every category there are up to 4 ways to store the prices Thank you for your proposal, It is a smart way to solve it. I will also think again about the design of these flows.

Comment: @Paplusc OK; but is `NPlayers` unique overall, or only within a "level-1" category? These constraints and sample data are missing from your question, which is why it's attracting close-votes.